# Как кастомизировать FAB?

Tags: java, android

Просто вопрос, почему нельзя было сделать нормальную FAB кнопку? Что за извращения с ней придумали?

Просто нужна вот такая кнопка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто аква цвет кнопка , по кругу белый контур

Почему то нельзя задать кнопке как это везде свой бекграунд и сделать там так допустим

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/topaz">

</solid>
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#FFF">

</stroke>
<padding
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp">

</padding>

</shape>
```

И все! Нет, нужно устанавливать

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/topaz"
```

который будет отвечать только за бекграунд, потом как то высталять boarders что то придумывать с цветом

В общем в итоге у меня получился вот такой код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ui.activities.cards.CardsActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_main"/>

<include layout="@layout/content_cards"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_card_activity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/topaz"
    app:elevation="16dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:borderWidth="2dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

но все равно цвет границы не появляется, просто вся кнопка одного цвета

Вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть кто то , кто выполнил такую тривиальную задачу, подскажите куда смотреть?

Comment: Как вариант: дорисовать кольцо на картинке `ic_plus`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005929/how-to-change-android-design-support-library-fab-button-border-color/33008431#33008431, попробуйте так